# ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator (variation)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I've read all the questions I can find on SO pertaining to this error, and they don't quite describe this situation. In those others, people are doing things like referencing only one of the aliased tables (from one side of the union) in the order by - I understand why SQLS complains in all the other questions I've read, about this particular error.

I can't see why SQL Server is taking issue with this `order by`; the only columns mentioned in the order by are definitely members of the result set select:

```
--example data:
-- a,b,c
-- 1, ,2
--  ,3,5

SELECT    1 AS a, null AS b, 2 AS c INTO #tmp
UNION
SELECT null AS a,    3 AS b, 5 AS c 

--let's call it a lame version of a rollup
SELECT * FROM #tmp            --detail rows
UNION ALL
SELECT a, b, SUM(c) FROM #tmp --summary row
GROUP BY a, b

--the problem
ORDER BY COALESCE(a, b);

DROP TABLE #tmp;
```

The result set contains column `a` and `b`, there's no ambiguity that I can see.. Even aliasing everything (differently) doesn't help:

```
SELECT t.a AS z, t.b AS y, t.c FROM #tmp t
UNION ALL
SELECT u.a AS z, u.b AS y, SUM(c) AS c FROM #tmp u
GROUP BY u.a, u.b
ORDER BY COALESCE(z, y);
```

In fact, bizarrely, SQL Server seems to complain even more:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Invalid column name 'z'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Invalid column name 'z'.           --why complain twice?
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Invalid column name 'y'.
Msg 104, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator.
```

The only thing that does work is wrapping it up as another select:

```
SELECT * FROM(
  SELECT * FROM #tmp
  UNION ALL
  SELECT a, b, SUM(c) AS c FROM #tmp
  GROUP BY u.a, u.b
) a
ORDER BY COALESCE(a, b);

SELECT * FROM(
  SELECT t.a AS z, t.b AS y, t.c FROM #tmp t
  UNION ALL
  SELECT u.a AS z, u.b AS y, SUM(c) AS c FROM #tmp u
  GROUP BY u.a, u.b
) z
ORDER BY COALESCE(z, y);
```

Which is what I thought, conceptually, SQL Server was doing with its result set before it processed the `order by` anyway.. So what gives?

Comment: That rule makes perfect sense. Think again!

Comment: @CauisJard . . . You understand how to fix the problem, so I don't really understand the question.  SQL Server has arcane rules about the use of aliases, that is all.

Comment: "The result set contains column a and b", yes, but not `COALESCE(a, b)`, which is what you want to order by.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sometimes I ask questions not because I need some solution, I'm keen to know more about what wonky logic inside SQL server causes the problem

Comment: @HoneyBadger I understand your point within the context of the first non-subquery form, but when else has that mattered, outside of a union? Why does it work in the subquery version, when it's not a member of the select list there either?

Comment: I think the question makes much sense. `a`and `b` are both in the select list, so it should be possible to order by `coalesce(a, b)`. I consider it a flaw that SQL Server throws an error (and many other DBMS too, seeing Caius Jard's answer).

Comment: @jarlh: I did think again and still don't see any sense in that rule. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Consider: create table t (a int, b int); insert into t values (1,1), (2,2), (1,3); select distinct a from t order by b;

Comment: @jarlh: That can't work, because `b` is not in the select list. But `select distinct a from t order by coalesce(a, 0)` should work, shouldn't it? Caius Jard selects `a` and `b`, but is not allowed to order by `coalesce(a, b)`. That doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, Seems like I commented the title without reading all the rest... Shame on me. (Yes, `order by coalesce(a, 0)` should work.)

Comment: (And I'm `UNION ALL`ing, so there is also no hiding/aggregating of values that I want to order by)

Comment: Correct, `UNION ALL` doesn't need that restriction.

Comment: It could be worth asking this in dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

As per note from HoneyBadger, it seems one must really just take SQLS at the error message face value and not assume that it builds a result set from the union query, aliased with the names given to columns in the leading select, that is then ordered..

This...

```
SELECT a, b, COALESCE(a,b) FROM t
UNION ALL
SELECT a, b, COALESCE(a,b) FROM u
ORDER BY COALESCE(a,b)
```

...works, presumably because it directly specifies `COALESCE(a,b)` in the select list as well as the ORDER BY

This...

```
SELECT * FROM(
  SELECT a, b FROM t
  UNION ALL
  SELECT a, b FROM u
)z
ORDER BY COALESCE(a,b)
```

...works, presumably because the query being ordered doesn't contain a UNION

Interesting mix of results from other DBs using the non-working form:

Oracle:

> ORA-01785: ORDER BY item must be the number of a SELECT-list expression

PostGres:

> ERROR: invalid UNION/INTERSECT/EXCEPT ORDER BY clause Detail: Only result column names can be used, not expressions or functions. Hint: Add the expression/function to every SELECT, or move the UNION into a FROM clause

MySQL:

> (works)

Comment: That's interesting. I wonder why all those DBMS struggle to perform the sort. Should be easy peasy; with both `a` and `b` being in the select list, what keeps them from using them in the sort expression?

Comment: Oracle's error message seems to indicate it does some kind of conversion from `COALESCE(a,b)` to an ordinal position, which makes me think it's expecting to find it in the select list so it can swap e.g. `SELECT a,b,COALESCE(a,b) ORDER BY COALESCE(a,b)` into `SELECT a,b,COALESCE(a,b) ORDER BY 3` but it only complains in the case of a union..