# SQLite query for retrieve data Order By

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

```
(TableMain)
Task_Id  Task       DateTime          Repetition    Snooze_Time
8        Call esha  2020-3-15 12:29   1             5
9        Meeting    2020-3-15 11:50   1             1

(TableRoutine)
Task_Id  Task       DateTime          Repetition    Snooze_Time
1        Go to GYM  2020-3-15 14:18   0             0
```

I have two tables in SQLite

I need result like this in Order By DateTime:
(Column DateTime in both table is data type of DateTime of SQLite)
I'm using this query to merge two tables data. But I need data in below formate.

```
SELECT Task, DateTime FROM TableMain UNION ALL SELECT Task, DateTim FROM TableRoutine
```

But I need data in below formate.

```
Task        DateTime       
Meeting     2020-3-15 11:50 
Call esha   2020-3-15 12:29
Go to GYM   2020-3-15 14:18
```

Is it possible to retrieve data like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You even do not need a subquery:

```
SELECT Task, DateTime FROM TableMain 
UNION ALL 
SELECT Task, DateTime FROM TableRoutine
order by DateTime
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/d01a7/1)

Answer (score 2):

The general pattern is to either just stick an ORDER BY on the end, or to wrap what you have written already in another select, and ORDER BY it:

Either:

```
SELECT Task, DateTime FROM TableMain 
UNION ALL 
SELECT Task, DateTim FROM TableRoutine
ORDER BY DateTime
```

Or:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT Task, DateTime FROM TableMain 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT Task, DateTim FROM TableRoutine
) x
ORDER BY x.DateTime
```

See which one works out for you - some databases sometimes refuse to do the first form. For example there are a lot of database that won't do this:

```
SELECT a, b FROM table1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT a, b FROM table2
ORDER BY COALESCE(a,b)
```

And the second form is required(or some other trick like selecting coalesce(a,b) from each too)

---

Avoid using words that are typically reserved in programming languages, as column names (like DateTime)

Comment: Just curious why this answer was acccepted then I accepted and you accepted another answer that is identical?

Comment: @CaiusJard: By "identical" you mean you copying that query from my answer, right? ;-)

Comment: @juergend Not at all; you can see from my replicating the guy's typo on his second column name that it was copied from his question. Mine also is better formatted to the OPs pretty print, plus surrounding advice as to why I presented two forms as further indication that my effort was my own. If you're in any doubt as to whether I was aware of the option of tacking an order by onto the end of a union all'd block before you enlightened me, see [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52478265/order-by-items-must-appear-in-the-select-list-if-the-statement-contains-a-union) ;)

Comment: actually I'm seeing the juregend the answer above you and also the UNION ALL query was helped by him so I accepted his answer. But thanks to u too for that naming tip. I applied that for my database